# Port forwarding Webserver Python

Tags: python, sockets, port, forwarding

I'm trying to create a port forwarding script that runs a webserver. Once you visit the webserver it should forward the user to the first web server in the array that runs on another port.

Every time a refresh happens in the browser the page needs to change according to the webserver where the user should be redirected to. Every page from a webserver has another color so that I can see if the server is redirecting me to the correct one.

Unfortunately, with the current code it does not work. The port changes which is good but the content of the page won't change.

Here is the code:

```
import socket
import threading
import sys
import time

def handle(buffer):
    return buffer

def transfer(src, dst, direction):
    src_name = src.getsockname()
    src_address = src_name[0]
    src_port = src_name[1]
    dst_name = dst.getsockname()
    dst_address = dst_name[0]
    dst_port = dst_name[1]

    buffer = ' '
    while buffer:
        buffer = src.recv(1024)
        if buffer:
            if direction:
                print("[+] %s:%d >>> %s:%d [%d]" % (src_address, src_port, dst_address, dst_port, len(buffer)))
            else:
                print("[+] %s:%d <<< %s:%d [%d]" % (dst_address, dst_port, src_address, src_port, len(buffer)))
            dst.sendall(buffer)
        else:
            break;

def server(local_host, local_port, remote_host, remote_port, max_connection):
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind((local_host, local_port))
    server_socket.listen(5)

    server_queue = [9999, 8888, 7777] # connect with first port in array

    new_remote_port = server_queue[0]

    connected = True
    while True:
        try:
            new_remote_port = server_queue[0]

            # connect to remote server
            try:
                local_socket, local_address = server_socket.accept()
                remote_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

                print('[+] Server started [%s:%d]' % (local_host, local_port))
                print('[+] Connect to [%s:%d] to get the content of [%s:%d]' % (local_host, local_port, remote_host, new_remote_port))

                remote_socket.connect((remote_host, new_remote_port))
            except socket.error:
                connected = False
                remote_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                print("Connection lost... reconnecting")
                while not connected:
                    try:
                        remote_socket.connect((remote_host, new_remote_port))
                        connected = True
                        print("Re-connection succesful")
                    except socket.error:
                        time.sleep(2)
            else:
                print("Starting threads!!")
                s = threading._start_new_thread(transfer, (remote_socket, local_socket, False))
                r = threading._start_new_thread(transfer, (local_socket, remote_socket, True))

        except socket.error:
            connected = False
            remote_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            print("Connection lost... reconnecting")
            while not connected:
                try:
                    remote_socket.connect((remote_host, new_remote_port))
                    connected = True
                    print("Re-connection succesful")
                except socket.error:
                    time.sleep(2)
        else: # on success
            last_used_port = server_queue.pop(0) # pop left
            print("Last used port: " + str(last_used_port))
            server_queue.append(last_used_port) # append to end of array
            print("[+] Connection setup succesful")

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 5:
        print("Usage : ")
        print("\tpython %s [L_HOST] [L_PORT] [R_HOST] [R_PORT]" % (sys.argv[0]))
        print("Example : ")
        print("\tpython %s 127.0.0.1 8888 127.0.0.1 22" % (sys.argv[0]))
        print("Author : ")
        print("\tWangYihang <wangyihanger@gmail.com>")
        exit(1)
    LOCAL_HOST = sys.argv[1]
    LOCAL_PORT = int(sys.argv[2])
    REMOTE_HOST = sys.argv[3]
    REMOTE_PORT = int(sys.argv[4])
    MAX_CONNECTION = 0x10
    server(LOCAL_HOST, LOCAL_PORT, REMOTE_HOST, REMOTE_PORT, MAX_CONNECTION)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Webserver code

```
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8888
Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: I don't think there's any obvious problem with your code.  It seems to work.  Are you sure your web server isn't just caching the response from the initial request?  Try having your web servers send the [`Cache-Control: no-cache`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) header as a first pass to see if that's what's happening.

Comment: In fact if you really want to be sure, forget about browsers and web servers for a second.  For example, I just tested this using netcat (`nc`).  I ran several servers with `nc -l 9999`, `nc -l 8888` and so on, then I ran your proxy server on port 5555, and then ran a few clients just by running `nc localhost 5555`.  Once you've confirmed that that's working as you expect, then you can worry about things like web servers and browsers, which is more likely where your issue lies.

Comment: @Iguananaut Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, the Cache-Control header causes issues, the page won't even load. I included my webserver code above so if you want, you can try it and see if it works. Please let me know if it does.

Comment: "Unfortunately, the Cache-Control header causes issues, the page won't even load".  I'm not really sure what you mean here; that doesn't make sense.  I suggest you look at my other suggestion of just ensuring your TCP-level forwarding works first (there is nothing in your code related to HTTP after all).

Comment: It's possible you are actually experiencing this bug with Python's simple HTTP server: https://bugs.python.org/issue31639

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little server I wrote to test your code:

```
import contextlib
import select
import textwrap
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from socketserver import TCPServer, ThreadingMixIn


SERVERS = [
    (7777, 'red'),
    (8888, 'green'),
    (9999, 'blue')
]


class ThreadedTCPServer(ThreadingMixIn, TCPServer):
    # Don't join on threads before exiting
    daemon_threads = True


class ColorHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    """HTTP request handler that just generates different colored pages."""

    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path != '/':
            self.send_error(404)
            return

        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        self.send_header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
        self.end_headers()

        color = getattr(self.server, 'color', 'white')

        self.wfile.write(textwrap.dedent(f"""\
            <html>
              <head>
                <title>{color}</title>
                <style type="text/css">
                body {{
                  background-color: {color};
                }}
                </style>
              </head>
              <body></body>
            </html>""").encode('utf-8'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    servers = []
    with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
        for port, color in SERVERS:
            server = ThreadedTCPServer(('', port), ColorHandler)
            server.color = color
            servers.append(stack.enter_context(server))

        # select loop
        while True:
            try:
                read, write, err = select.select(servers, [], [])
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                break
            for server in read:
                server.handle_request()
```

It seems to work with Chrome.  However, there is still a problem, I think with your code, which is that your `transfer` thread will block on `src.recv` after each request.  So now you will need to rework your code to close the connection to the forwarded port when the local connection is terminated.